# How to split the data in the data frame in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I used the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
pandas_bigram = pd.DataFrame(bigram_data)
print pandas_bigram
```

I got output as below

```
                                0
0                     ashoka -**0
1                 - wikipedia,**1
2               wikipedia, the**2
3                     the free**2
4            free encyclopedia**2
5          encyclopedia ashoka**1
6                  ashoka from**2
7              from wikipedia,**1
8               wikipedia, the**2
9                     the free**2
10           free encyclopedia**2
```

My question is How to split this data frame. So, that i will get data in two rows. the data here is separated by "**".

Comment: Are you reading bigram_data from csv file?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df= [" ashoka -**0","- wikipedia,**1","wikipedia, the**2"]
df=pd.DataFrame(df)

print(df)
                   0
0        ashoka -**0
1    - wikipedia,**1
2  wikipedia, the**2
```

Use [split](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) function: The method split() returns a list of all the words in the string, using str as the separator (splits on all whitespace if left unspecified), optionally limiting the number of splits to num.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df[0].str.split('*',1).tolist(),
                                       columns = ['0','1'])

print(df1)

                0   1
0        ashoka -  *0
1    - wikipedia,  *1
2  wikipedia, the  *2
```